# Terraform - problem with filter by value !=

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to get list of private subnets based on a tag. The public subnets have a tag subnet-type set, but the private ones don't have that tag. So, i am trying to filter by the ones that DO NOT match the tag.

```
data "aws_subnets" "i_subnet_id" {   filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [var.i_vpc_id]   }

  filter {
    name = "tag:SubnetType"
    values != ["abc"]   } }
```

If i set values = ["abc"] it works fine and I get the list of public subnets, but i need to exclude the ones with "abc", when i set it to values != ["abc"] it says

> "an argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument,
> use = sign to introduce argument value"

Any idea what's the issue here? Thanks.

Comment: *"Any idea what's the issue here?"* - yes, terraform does not support that syntax, that is not how things work. And what you want cannot be achieved using data sources alone, you can try to filter them out after having retrieved them via the data source.

Comment: @luk2302, TF does seem to have != option, are you suggesting that it's just not supported at this place? In any case, will try to see how to filter out after the values are fetched. Thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: Yes, in an expression obviously you can check for inequality, but you are not specifying an expression here, you are *assigning* something to the variable / parameter `values`.

Comment: No, you have it very much backwards here. You are basically assigning values that will be used to craft a query against AWS. If I ask you 'what fruit do you want for breakfast' you cannot just answer 'not an apple', that is not a valid response. Terraform asks you to supply the subnet type and you cannot respond with 'not XYZ'.